# Using external data sources in BQ with specific generation from Google Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to use external data sources in a BQ select statement with not the latest but a specific generation of a file from Google Cloud Storage.

I currently use the following:

```
val sourceFile = "gs://test-bucket/flights.csv"
val queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                .addTableDefinition("tmpTable",
                        ExternalTableDefinition.newBuilder(sourceFile, schema, format)
                                .setCompression("GZIP")
                                .build())
                .build();
        bigQuery.query(queryConfig)
```

I tried to set the sourceFile variable as follows:

```
val sourceFile = "gs://test-bucket/flights.csv#123456789"
```

But that leads to the following error:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The query specified one or more federated data sources but not all of them were scanned. It usually indicates incorrect uri specification or a 'limit' clause over a union of federated data sources that was satisfied without having to read all sources.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "The query specified one or more federated data sources but not all of them were scanned. It usually indicates incorrect uri specification or a 'limit' clause over a union of federated data sources that was satisfied without having to read all sources.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

When I do not use a generation it works fine. I also checked with `gsutils stat gs://test-bucket/flights.csv#123456789` if the file exists with this generation

Is it possible to specify a generation here?

Comment: Is this happening just with this version or with all of them?

Comment: I tried two different files each has one version

Comment: Google Cloud Support here! After further investigation and seeing that this is not documented anywhere I understand that versioned objects should work as non versioned objects do. Therefore, I have filed a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/139449806) which you can track and see the progress on the resolution of this topic. Please feel free to add additional information to the public issue in order to help to speed up the investigation.