# Error form google big query The query specified one or more federated data sources but not all of them were scanned

Tags: google-bigquery

I recently encountered the following error while working with external tables **The query specified one or more federated data sources but not all of them were scanned**.  The error affects a few models, where as other models with similar syntax run without an issue.  The set up is as follows,

1. I am using hive partitioning specifying that there is a path component **arrivaldat:e**
   gs://bucket/mydata/{arrivaldate:DATE}
2. I am specifying partition pruning **arrivaldate between DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL X DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in my particular case, the issue stems from the fact that, there are no partitions satisfying the range specified by the WHERE clause.  Widening the window X to include at least one partition seems to have fixed this issue.  As a more generic case as also seen in [similar error #57492661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492661/using-external-data-sources-in-bq-with-specific-generation-from-google-storage), it would appear that the error stems from GBQ not finding any files